# Mysql no replication lag but one table is not updating

Tags: mysql, database-replication, master-slave

I've a problem with Mysql replication
We have DC-DR setup an mysql running on both master and slave. When we run "Show slave status" more or less it gives 0 sec lag and also all the tables except one are updating fine. But for one particular table it happens that it is updated after some time interval. say sometimes after 1hr sometimes after 3-4 hrs etc.

Comment: Please add more detail

Comment: there are say n number tables in DC and DR, replication is running fine with zero lag, but when I try to match count of total number of rows of a particular table of both the servers I got that particular table is not getting updated on DR on a regular basis. This happens only for one particular table. Say the table has updated on 14:30, then 13:25 then 16:50 pm respectively.